# what is the alternate of chunk_size while using parquete in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, bioinformatics, parquet

hi previously i have used .csv file for my dataframe but due to some problem i have choosen to work with parquet file, im getting "read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunk' " Error.
i'm using following code-:

```
reader = pd.read_parquet("Org_Proteins_Diseases.parquet", engine='pyarrow', chunk=1000) 
#chunksize depends with you colsize
```

Answer (score 0):

The data in parquet file is organized in small batches, called `row_groups`, with a default size of 64mb.

You can read the data by row groups instead of reading the whole file, but you have to use pyarrow for that (it's not available in pandas)

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def read_by_row_group(file_name):
    parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(file_name)
    for row_group in range(parquet_file.num_row_groups):
        yield parquet_file.read_row_group(row_group).to_pandas()
        
for df in read_by_row_group("Org_Proteins_Diseases.parquet"):
    print(len(df))
```

Comment: i think pyarrow can be used as engine in pandas, Please confirm :)

Comment: Yes it can, but it only means that pyarrow is what is being used to load the data, calling this function https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html But this function doesn't support `chunk`.

Comment: i have a function which i have written for .csv file but not sure how i should include with your code, can we connect on discord?